# Fuzziness gets ignored for query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run "fuzzy" query_string search, any ideas what might be wrong? Fuzziness parameter itself is valid for query_string and no exception is thrown.

Finds one result:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "title",
          "query": "index"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cannot find anything:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "title",
          "query": "indexa",
          "fuzziness": 9000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a query string, you'd have to explicitly use the ["fuzzy operator"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness) `~`.

Try:

```
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "indexa~",
      "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use a [fuzzy match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) if you know which field you're searching on and you don't need the query string capabilities (e.g. allowing the user to use operators like `AND` or `OR` or introduce custom boosts etc.)

```
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "indexa",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
```

Also note that in both cases, `fuzziness` [only accepts the values `1`, `2` or `AUTO`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness), so 9000 is not a valid value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I've set fuzziness to 9000 to ensure/show that it's fuzzy as possible (whitch is valid). [Fuzzinees](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) can be 0..2, 3..5, >5, but yes, I agree, "AUTO" is recommended.

Yes, I'll find  document this way, but still, using wildcards seems to be the only way to find same document when only "nde" term is given for "this title is index"

    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "indexa~"
    }

Comment: The docs are slightly confusing here: `0..2`, `3..5` and `>5` are in fact just the descriptions of different cases for which `AUTO` behaves differently. The only valid values for string fields are `0`, `1`, `2` and `AUTO`.